# Java - Use getService method who have Class<T> for parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have this method to get my services

```java
public <T extends ServiceInterface> T getService(Class<T> aServiceClass);
```

I would like to instantiate the class "MyService" that extends to ServiceInterface with this method.

How to do that? should I make a `new MyService` object to pass it as a parameter? but if I do that the get service method will not be useful.

Comment: obj.getService(MyService.class); Pass Class type like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to create a class `MyService`, that extends `ServiceInterface`. And you want to get your Service by the method `getService(Class<T> aServiceClass>)`, right? That would look like this (but please split the classes in different files):

```
package test;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService m = getService(MyService.class);
        //m.someMethod(...);
    }

    public static <T extends ServiceInterface> T getService(Class<T> aServiceClass) {
        return null; //??
    }

    //class MyService
    public class MyService extends ServiceInterface{

        //someMethods...

    }

    //class ServiceInterface
    public class ServiceInterface {

        public <T extends ServiceInterface> T getService(Class<T> aServiceClass) {
            return null; //whatever the method is doing
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary for ServiceInterface (or MyService) to have a getService method. That method is just a method in some other class.

Comment: Okay, I removed the method. But this is how you can call the method `getService(...)`.